# iOS localized images don't appear to be localized

Tags: ios, localization

This is one of those silly simple problems, that is so simple I can't figure out what is causing the problem.

I localized 80 or so images by clicking the image, the localization button and clicking the languages french and chinese and the folders were created. [FYI our app already has string localization implemented and working]. I then copied the translated images into their respective folders.

Now I can click the image's left arrow drop down, then click the french and chinese image and I see a french and chinese version of the image. I then restart the simulator, then change the language to french and run my app and the strings are all in french, but the images I localized are still in english [same with when i try chinese].

Additional info:

- my images are in their respective en.lproj, etc folders with no images in the base folder.
- When I check "Copy Bundle Resources" the images are shown to exist in the base folder; their is only 1 image referenced per resource; ie. it doesn't explicitly show all different language images.
- I've tried ios 5.1 and 6, and both retina and not retina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have everything set up correctly. I'd recommend testing on an actual iOS device.

In my experience, the simulator is pretty glitchy when it comes to localization.  Here are some workarounds, none will work 100% of the time unfortunately:

- Set the locale of your Mac to the same locale as inside the simulator
- Reset using *iOS Simulator* -> *Reset Content and Settings…*
- Clear the Derived Data in *Organizer* -> *Projects* -> *Derived Data*
- Use *Product* -> *Clean* before you rebuild

Submit a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) about it!

Comment: Hazzah! I finally got it to work on the iPhone.
At first it still didn't work, but I deleted the app from the iPhone and tried again and it worked.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For localization, it's best to test on a device.

Try deleting your app from the device. Do a clean. Then run again. This forces Xcode to copy everything over again, including your new files. Whenever you modify settings bundles or resources, deleting and re-building is best.

Comment: And don't forget to clean the target!

Comment: I went through "Reset Content and Settings" in the iOS simulator, is that enough (it deleted the app and reset all the settings)?
How do I clean the target? (btw thanks for the response :D)

Comment: I tried product > clean, but that didn't help. The english image is still showing up when I'm in french.